# Image Upload Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm currently in the process of building an image upload component using VueJS.
The input element is hidden from view so as to have an empty image tag superimposed on top of it. When the user clicks on the image, the upload file prompt appears and allows the user to choose a file. However, if the page loads and that profile accessing it already has a profile image, the component is supposed to load that image and show it. That profile image is superimposed on top of the input tag so as when the user chooses to update the image the same thing as described above happens.

Using Vueify, I have the following:

```
<template>
    <div class="image-upload-container">
    <div class="container__image-container">
        <form method="POST"
              id="photo_upload"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
        >

            <input type="file" />

            <img src="  "/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
</div>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        props: ['type'],

        data() {
            return{
                show: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I initialize the component:

```
import ImageUpload from '../components/ImageUpload.vue';

new Vue({
    el: '#image-upload',

    components: { ImageUpload },
});
```

Then load it on the page:

```
<div id="image-upload">
    <image-upload></image-upload>
</div>
```

My question centres around how I should load the image path coming from the server. I'm using Laravel and Blade. Should I perhaps go about doing this:

```
<div id="image-upload">
    <image-upload path={{ $profile->image }}></image-upload>
</div>
```

And then have a prop named **path** that initializes the **img** tag in the template?